# When calling a worker in javascript where exactly do I set the MIME type?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, mime, worker

I am trying to replicate a very simple example of calling a worker in plain javascript. I'm getting an error due to wrong MIME type but I cannot figure out where the program is finding the default MIME type or where I can set a type that will make it happy.

If I set "type=text/plain" in the  call    the call fails entirely. If I leave that parameter off, the call fires cme.js successfully, but the call to the worker fails with
"Loading Worker from “http://localhost/backfillWorker.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)."

For posting this I reduced the worker to an absolute minimum and am simply trying to send it a text string.

So my question is,  where in this code should I be setting the "type" so that this much code will run and call the worker successfully?  I've tried the  line at the top of the html.  I've tried all variations I can think of in the  call. Nothing works.

Except, sigh, the example from the book never defines "type" anywhere and it runs fine. Is my browser doing something to me? I'm using firefox.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/octet-stream" >
    <!-- I suspect the line above is where TYPE needs to be set?? -->
</head>
<body>
  
    <h3> cme.html </h3>
     
    <!-- if I add "type=xxx here, it wont run cme.js, if I don't, the worker fails" -->
<script src="/js/cme.js"  ></script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
// ==================start of cme.js ==================
 
function backfill() {
    if (window.Worker) {
      const myWorker = new Worker("backfillWorker.js");

        myWorker.postMessage("Hello");
        console.log('Message posted to worker');  // this much fires but in point of fact an error has occurred asynch
    // Loading Worker from “http://localhost/backfillWorker.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

        /*
      myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
        //result.textContent = e.data;
        console.log("Message received from worker");
        alert(" message received back");
      }
      */

    } else {
      console.log('Your browser doesn\'t support web workers.');
    }

}
 
backfill();
//========== end of cme.js ==================================
```

and

```
// ============ strart of backfillWorker.js ==============================
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Worker: Message received from main script');
  alert("made it inside backfillWorker.js");
 // const result = e.data[0] * e.data[1];
   
  //  const workerResult = 'Result: ' + result;
  //  console.log('Worker: Posting message back to main script');
  //postMessage("goodbye");
   
}
// ======================= end of backfillWorker.js ===========
```

Comment: What server do you use to host your files on localhost? and if you enter `http://localhost/backfillWorker.js` in the address bar of your browser, do you get the correct script or some error page?

Comment: The URL you pass to `Worker(url)` is relative to the document's `baseURL`. So if your worker script is also in the directory `/js/`, you need to do `new Worker("/js/backfillWorker.js");` The mime type error is certainly because you hit a 404 html error page.

Comment: Thank you both.  You were correct that my directory was wrong. Firefox didn't tell me the 404 error but Chrome did. Now it works.  I'll delete this whole post tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas and Kaiido, this is fixed. The problem was indeed a 404 error. wrong directory, visible in Chrome but not in Firefox.